# Solution for setting additional custom options on nodes (In Drupal 8)

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7 I had a field collection with a few dozen fields that were used to set theme related options on a node. A few examples on what these node fields could do:

- Change color of header
- Change width of layout
- Add a background image to the page
- Exclude certain regions from the page (page title, footer etc)

Most of these options actually override theme settings, but some settings are unique to this node options feature.

For these node options to take effect, a lot of custom preprocessing code was written in the theme layer. It also generates a large amount of database tables, since each field has its own tables. It's not an efficient solution.

Does anyone know of a Drupal 8 solution that could be a more efficient way to add settings to the node form? Just asking here before writing something custom to avoid doing duplicate work.

Comment: keyvalue storage + hook_form_alter + hook_preprocess + hook_node_insert + hook_node_update + hook_node_delete

Comment: yeah we might go with a low-level approach like that, but we also need to support exporting these settings with things default content and other export/import solutions so might use something a bit more high-level like configuration entities.

Comment: the lower level approach is also less suited to managing images (files) in the node options.